# Concatenation within echo of array

Tags: php, arrays

Very simple but this echo isn't returning anything. I want to concatenate 2 values from an included PHP array file so I don't have to write the code twice. What am I writing incorrectly?

```
<?php echo $lang['work' . 'title']; ?>
```

Among others I have tried

```
<?php echo $lang['work', 'title']; ?>
<?php echo $lang['work' 'title']; ?>
```

Comment: print_r($lang) to check if the worktitle is correct key? or just use array_key_exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo $lang['work'], $lang['title']; ?>
```

Check out [php array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) documentation.